# How to filter RDD relying on hash map?

Tags: scala, rdd, orc

I'm new to using spark and scala but I have to solve the following problem:
I have one ORC file containing rows which I have to check against a certain condition comming from a hash map.

I build the hash map (filename,timestamp) with 120,000 entries this way (getTimestamp returns an `Option[Long]` type):

```
val tgzFilesRDD = sc.textFile("...")
val fileNameTimestampRDD = tgzFilesRDD.map(itr => {
    (itr, getTimestamp(itr))
})
val fileNameTimestamp = fileNameTimestampRDD.collect.toMap
```

And retrieve the RDD with 6 million entries like this:

```
val sessionDataDF = sqlContext.read.orc("...")
case class SessionEvent(archiveName: String, eventTimestamp: Long)
val sessionEventsRDD = sessionDataDF.as[SessionEvent].rdd
```

And do the check:

```
val sessionEventsToReport = sessionEventsRDD.filter(se => {
    val timestampFromFile = fileNameTimestamp.getOrElse(se.archiveName, None)
    se.eventTimestamp < timestampFromFile.getOrElse[Long](Long.MaxValue)
})
```

Is this the right and performant way to do it? Is there a caching recommended?
Will the Map `fileNameTimestamp` get shuffled to the clusters where the parititons where processed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fileNameTimestamp will get serialized for each task, and with 120,000 entries, it may be quite expensive.  You should broadcast large objects and reference the broadcast variables:

```
val fileNameTimestampBC = sc.broadcast(fileNameTimestampRDD.collect.toMap)
```

Now only one of these object will be shipped to each worker.  There is also no need to drop down to the RDD API, as the Dataset API has a filter method:

```
val sessionEvents = sessionDataDF.as[SessionEvent]
val sessionEventsToReport = sessionEvents.filter(se => {
    val timestampFromFile = fileNameTimestampBC.value.getOrElse(se.archiveName, None)
    se.eventTimestamp < timestampFromFile.getOrElse[Long](Long.MaxValue)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `fileNameTimestamp` Map you `collect`ed exists on Spark Master Node. In order to be referenced efficiently like this in a query, the worker nodes need to have access to it. This is done by [broadcasting](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables).

In essence, you rediscovered [Broadcast Hash Join](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html): You are left joining sessionEventsRDD with tgzFilesRDD to gain access to the optional timestamp and then you filter accordingly.

When using RDDs, you need to explicitly code the joining strategy. Dataframes/Datasets API has a query optimiser that can make the choice for you. You can also explicitly ask the API to use the above broadcast join technique behind the scenes. You can find examples for both approaches [here](http://henning.kropponline.de/2016/12/11/broadcast-join-with-spark/).

Let me know if this is clear enough :)

Comment: Thx for the answer and links. Pointed me in the right direction, like the one from @BrianCajes.

Comment: Happy to be helpful Matthias. The "default" was of saying thanks for a helpful answer in StackOverflow is upvoting the answer ;)

Comment: I did vote but due to be a new member my vote is counted but not shown.